# Does LINQ to SQL or any other LINQ enabled ORM support many association filtering?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, orm, entity-framework-4

Apparently, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929079/querying-an-entitys-child-collections-in-entity-framework-4-1) you cannot query a many relationship without loading the entire collection. In other words, it's a `LINQ to Objects` instead of a `LINQ to Entities` query.

E.g.

```
Category category = db.Categories.Find(1);
var productsThatStartWithA = category.Products.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("A")).ToList();
```

The above query loads all products in that category, and the filter is applied afterwards.

**Question #1**

Is this correct? I can't believe how stupid this is.

**Question #2**

Does `LINQ to SQL` or any other `LINQ` enabled `ORM` handle this the way it's supposed to work?

---

The alternatives presented in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929079/querying-an-entitys-child-collections-in-entity-framework-4-1) and in [Slauma's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765422/does-linq-to-sql-or-any-other-linq-enabled-orm-support-many-association-filtering/6766263#6766263) answer are workarounds, not solutions. They require a reference to the context object, which is not available if you write code that is decoupled from the Entity Framework API, and/or your code is object-oriented, e.g.:

```
public class Category { 

   public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsThatStartWithA() {
      return this.Products.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("A")).ToList()
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. The answer in the linked questions gives you *two ways* to load a filtered navigation collection, doesn't it? Your example is LINQ to Objects, right (assuming that you have lazy loading for the Products property, then it's DB-query for the full collection and then LINQ to Objects on the loaded collection. If you don't have lazy loading your code would crash anyway.) But it's only LINQ to Objects because you don't use one of the approaches in the answer.

Comment: Your proposed code mixes concerns of an Entity Service and an Entity. There's a very good reason you don't have a context here. You might find [Mark Seeman's post on application boundaries informative.](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/31/AtTheBoundariesApplicationsAreNotObjectOriented.aspx)

Comment: @Craig Stuntz: It's just an example of what I'm trying to achieve, and what I think should be able to achieve using an ORM. It's not the point of this question to discuss design patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sad is that Linq to SQL actually provide much better support for this (with `DataLoadOptions.AssociateWith` but it is still not exactly what you want) whereas Linq to entities / EF provides only what you call workaround - even with respect to the implementation and existing difference between `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` it looks like correct solution.

What you want will require collection to expose `IQueryable` and internally call the code showed by @Slauma if collection is not loaded = linq-to-entities or common linq-to-objects on loaded collection. I'm not sure if it can work but you can play with it. Here you have some starting points:

- [Extra-Lazy Collection Count with EF 4.1 (Part 1)](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/03/28/extra-lazy-collection-count-with-ef-4-1-part-1/)
- [Extra-Lazy Collection Count with EF 4.1 (Part 2)](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/03/28/extra-lazy-collection-count-with-ef-4-1-part-2/)

Btw. you must turn off EF's lazy loading otherwise it will take precedence.

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct that queries like the queries in your example are only possible in memory (LINQ to Objects).

You can achieve filtered loading of the collection with two roundtrips to the DB - see option 1 in Ladislav's answer to the linked question. To translate this to your concrete example it would look like this:

```
Category category = db.Categories.Find(1);
var productsThatStartWithA = db.Entry(category)
    .Collection(c => c.Products)
    .Query()
    .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("A"))
    .ToList();
```

This doens't load the full `Products` collection but only a filtered set. It's LINQ to Entities and not LINQ to Objects and it works with and without lazy loading.

Moreover you can achieve the same result with a single roundtrip and a single query by projecting into an anonymous type:

```
var result = db.Categories.Where(c => c.Id == 1)
    .Select(c => new
    {
        Category = c,
        ProductsStartingWithA = c.Products.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("A"))
    })
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Here you have your category and filtered products collection in `result.Category` and `result.ProductsStartingWithA`.

Comment: These are workarounds, not solutions. Both alternatives require a reference to the context object, which is not available if you write code that is decoupled from the Entity Framework API.

Comment: @Max Toro: It's not possible to issue a database query (with or without filtering) without a living context. How should that work? The context is the only gateway to the database. You must have a context either explicitely (as in my examples) or implicitely/hidden in proxy objects for lazy loading. In both cases there must be a reference to a EF context instance which has not been disposed. If you are in a disconnected scenario there is no hope to query something from the database. This won't work with any ORM.

Comment: See the example added to the question.

Comment: @Max Toro: It wasn't clear to me before your Edit that you don't want to reference a context explicitely. `Products` must be some kind of proxy collection which references the context internally to bring your method to life. (It can't be a simple `List<T>` or `HashSet<T>` or something.) I can only tell you that EFs proxies don't support to run a filtered query on the DB. With EF you have to use one of the solutions above. It might be possible that other ORMs have this capability but I don't know.

Comment: But I doubt there can be a solution at all as long as you want to have ordinary collection interfaces/classes in your model - like `ICollection<T>`. Whatever ORM you use you would only have the methods of those collection types. Their LINQ extension methods are always methods for `IEnumerable<T>` which means LTO. If an ORM supports what you are looking for, you would have to change the collection types in your model to some custom type of that ORM (`IQueryableCollectionOfORMXYZ<T>`) or - in best case - perhaps `IQueryable<T>`. But it's beyond my horizon how this could look like in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember the difference between LINQ to Entities and LINQ to Objects.

A `.Where()` in LINQ to Entities will be converted to SQL. A `.Where` in LINQ to Objects won't.

You can *really easily* use SQL to restrict a list of entities by using LINQ to Entities. You can also *really easily* avoid silently and invisibly generating DB queries by using LINQ to Objects.

In short, the difference exists precisely because, as you imply, it's good to use SQL sometimes (but not every time!). If that seems "stupid" to you, then I'd gently suggest you spend some time getting over how you expect things to work and learn how they actually do work. It **does** make sense if your expectations align with the implementation.

Comment: If you *truly* do (your down-voting this answer, frankly, makes me wonder if you're just letting off steam), then I agree with @Slauma.

Comment: Neither Slauma nor you are answering the question, that's the reason for the downvote.

Comment: You don't seem to have a real question; you have an assertion that LINQ to Entities (and LINQ to SQL, for the same reason) are doing something "wrong" by using the LINQ API in the way they are. I strongly disagree with that. **I think that Microsoft understands how to use LINQ.** Non-query objects are *supposed* to use L2O; you're insisting that they should not, despite multiple examples to the contrary, the fact that implementing your suggestion would hurt performance for common scenarios, and the fact that there are *simple* ways to do what you want which you don't seem to want to use.

Comment: I don't know the type of the object for `public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; }`, but it should be a query object. Either way, I can accept that if there are alternatives (other ORMs), that's my second (real) question.

Comment: No, EntityCollections are not queries. They're collections. Ditto for L2S.